# Htaccess redirect old blog permalinks to subdomain permalinks

Tags: .htaccess

I've tried various rules, but can't seem to get what I need.

I'd like to redirect old permalinks like this (with or w/o www)

```
Http://www.example.com/blog/2012/12/18/a-post-title/
```

To

```
Http://blog.example.com/2012/12/18/a-post-title/
```

For example, i have tried

```
RewriteRule blog\/(.+?)(-[0-9]+)?$ blog\.example\.com\/$1 [L,R=301]
```

What should the full condition/rule look like?

Comment: Is `blog/` a real directory?

Comment: Yes. It's a directory. example.com/blog

Comment: Oops. It is not. My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have this rule inside `blog/.htaccess` (not in site root):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/.*$ http://blog.example.com/$0 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Make sure to use a new browser for testing.

Comment: This actually seems to be redirecting to incorrectly. I made a mistake in my original post. I need it to redirect to http://blog.example.com/2012/12/18/a-post     note. Dropping the /blog subdirectory. Sorry

Comment: ok check updated answer. Make sure to use a new browser for testing.